# Null Firebase currentUser After Sign In Redirect

Tags: php, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a signIn page called index.html. When a user sign in, I would like to be redirected in a new page called home.html, showing the current user's email.

The problem is that I get a null currentUser.

file : index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Firebase Login</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
  <h3>Firebase Web login Example</h3>
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" />

  <button onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
</div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js">
</script>
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

file : index.js

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
 if (user) {
// User is signed in.

 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

 if(user != null){

  var email_id = user.email;

  window.location.href = "home.html"; //(!!!!!! REDIRECT)

  document.getElementById("userEmail).innerHTML = email_id;
 } 

 } else {
  // No user is signed in.

  document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

 }
 });


function login(){

 var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
 var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
// Handle Errors here.
var errorCode = error.code;
var errorMessage = error.message;

window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

// ...
});
}
```

file home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div id="userEmail"></div>

</body>
```

In the home.html file the current user has null value.

How can I show in the #userEmail (home.html) the user's email that signed in?

P.S. I have imported the Firebase scripts in the home.html file.

Answer (score 0):

The code after:
window.location.href = "home.html"; //(!!!!!! REDIRECT)
cannot be executed.

I would expect an infinite-loop with this code.

Try to check the location.pathname before redirecting.

```
if (window.location.pathname !== 'home.html') {
  window.location.href = 'home.html'
} else {
  // your code here... (insert email into div...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the user email in session and you can access it anywhere, until you make it null on logout.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have, just delete this line:

```
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

The reason is because this function should already handle the current User Status:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged
```